# What are all the facilities provided by Facebook to an application?

Tags: facebook

I'm not going to integrate my application into Facebook platform
I just registered my app to get the api key 
In that case what are all the facilities i can avail from facebook apart from using facebook for  authentication  
1. Can i get users friends list 
2. will my application be allowed to send notification or messages or emails to users friends 

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The obvious place to start to find out what the Facebook API offers would be [the Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

You'll be interested in the [`Friends.get`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.get/) and [`Notifications.send`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/) methods.

In other words, the answers to your questions are Yes and Yes.